# Calling Attach and Add supplying the same object as parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following relationships between some types A, B, C and X:

```
A->B->X
|->C->X
|->X
```

Now assume that i want to add a new A to the database and associate it with existing instances of B, C and X.

What i'm doing is this:

```
using (Context context = new Context())
{
  context.As.Attach(A);
  context.As.Add(A);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It seems to work but i'm not sure about it since Attach is usually used to attach existing instances.

This alternative does not work:

```
using (Context context = new Context())
{
  context.Bs.Attach(A.B);
  context.Cs.Attach(A.C);
  context.As.Add(A);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Because in this case X gets attached twice (A.B.X and A.C.X) and entity framework throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
```

Does it make sense to use my solution or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your solution makes sense - you have attached whole graph and changed just `A` to `Added` state. It can be also rewritten as:

```
using (Context context = new Context())
{
  context.As.Attach(A);
  context.Entry(A).State = EntityState.Added;
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In some complex scenarios it can be also useful to do that in reverse order - add all and change state of all existing items.